# Maven cannot obtain junit

Tags: java, maven, junit, dependencies

I have got a project that implements unit testing with `junit`. There is a `pom.xml` fragment

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, the project does not compile. The error in `pom.xml` looks like:

[image]

How to fix the error?

---

`mvn install` returns next error message

```
[INFO] C:\Users\loom\prj\src\main\java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] C:\Users\loom\prj\target\generated-sources\annotations:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\loom\prj\target\classes at 1548091925026
[ERROR] error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
[ERROR]         at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
[ERROR]         at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:31)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:64)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[INFO]  at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:161)
[INFO]  at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.196 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-21T20:32:06+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) on project prj: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

[There](https://pastebin.com/rcSNfc5Q) is a full log of `maven install`

---

Java and maven versions:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T22:49:05+03:00)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.5.3bin..
Java version: 10.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Users\loom\scoop\apps\openjdk\current
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

---

Plugin info follows:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>

        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

        <configuration>
            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
            <testSourceDir>src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

Comment: There is nothing woring with your code have tried a maven update on your IDE?

Comment: What are the results of running `mvn install` in the command line?

Comment: Do you have repositories section in your pom file?

Comment: @JBaruch - Thank you. I have updated the question.

Comment: @OlegUshakov - I haven't repositories section in the `pom.xml`

Comment: try to remove junit version.and run clean install.If it fails try to downgrade your junit version to a lower version

Comment: I am pretty sure the error on the build has nothing to do with junit. The resolution of the test phase happens after the compilation test, so it didn't even get to looking for JUnit.

Comment: Which Java version? Which Maven version ? Also please check on plain command line...and show the full logging output ...

Comment: @Loom : Please update your question with plugin details from pom file

Comment: @khmarbaise - I have expanded question with the information you meant

Comment: @GovindParashar - I have expanded question with the information you meant

Comment: @Loom : I have successfully build local project with   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
   <version>2.12.8</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.12</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> .   I have seen build failure error which is not related to junit. The Error related to your java version +  scala-library version + scala-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided information its kind of hard to tell what happens, I'll try to provide a couple of points that may lead you at the right direction:

Maven has a concept of phases configured for the default lifecycle that runs when you call `mvn install`

One can find a full list of phases at the bottom of [this page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

The 'test-compile' phase where junit comes into play first (because it needs to compile test classes that must have JUnit annotations) appears somewhere at the middle of the list (and then the 'test' phase that actually runs the tests)

My point is that from the attached stacktrace it looks like the build fails before it gets there. 
Probably somewhere during the initial compilation or even source generation phase.
The best would be to examine a full stacktrace and not only a partial snippet, maven always writes what exacly is being run at the moment.

Validate phase (the first one) obviously passes, so you don't have issues in pom.xml.
In addition, the definition of JUnit dependency itself (if its put into `<dependencies>` section also looks good). 
What made you think that the build fails solely because of JUnit library?

Maybe its some conflict of versions of Java/Scala/Maven? 
Another possible reason is a wrong configuration of plugin responsible for Scala sources compilation, or something is configured wrong during the source generation phase.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the folder **junit/junit** from your maven repository. Sometimes, maven gets stuck trying to download dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it does not help.